# Is List a value type or a reference type?

Tags: c#, list, value-type, reference-type

Is `List` a value type or a reference type?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23%20List%20-%20is%20it%20a%20value%20type%20or%20a%20reference%20type%3F gives you exactly the same http://www.gamedev.net/topic/549626-c-list---is-it-a-value-type-or-a-reference-type/ question on similar site... (As well as plenty of other links)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov,OMG,I did not see

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) is a reference type since it's a class.

Answer (score 9):

[List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) (a [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx)) is a reference type. See:

- [Value Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)
- [Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

the List is a class so it reference type

this class is [Generic Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx), you declare list of items the item type can be value type and reference type